# How can I pass a event and a parameter to a javascript function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    iDisplayLength: -1,
    ...
    ...

$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", gridClickHandler);

function gridClickHandler(oTable) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
```

I was told that the $(this) event will be passed to the function but I need to also pass something else as I found it gives an error relating to oTable.

How can I modify my call to gridClickHandler and the gridClickHandler function so it passes a reference to oTable and also so the $(this) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `oTable` is declared in an outer scope, the `gridClickHandler` function will have access to it, so you don't need to pass it manually. As a matter of fact, event handlers receive the event object as the first argument, so you're actually *shadowing* the TABLE reference.

For example:

```
var foo = 123;

var clickHandler = function ( foo ) {    
    // here, foo is not 123, but the event object  
    // the outer variable foo is shadowed by the local variable foo  
};
```

Just remove the first argument:

```
var gridClickHandler = function () {
```

Now, `oTable` is retrieved from the outer scope.

(Also notice, how I assign a anonymous function expression to a variable, instead of using a function declaration.)

Btw, inside the function, `this` refers to the TR element.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you mean by oTable being declared in outer scope.  oTable is declared in one .js file and the gridClickHandler is declared in another file with function gridClickHandler(oTable) {

Comment: Can you explain why you don't use the function declaration. Thanks.

Comment: @Gemma Is `oTable` a global variable? If not, how is the second .js file accessing it? (Non-global variables of one .js file, are not accessible to other .js files, unless you explicitly attach the value to some sorts of shared object.)

Comment: I don't think it's global which is maybe my problem. How can I make it into a global variable? oTable is created as a var inside the function refreshDone(responseText, entity) { }

Comment: @Gemma You need to make it available to the other .js file. There are different ways to do this. One would be to define a global variable which acts as your namespace (e.g. `var MYAPP = {};` outside of any function), and then assign properties to it (e.g. `MYAPP.oTable = ...;`). Now, the second .js file can create a local variable which stores that reference from your namespace (e.g. `var oTable = MYAPP.oTable`). I recommend a tutorial on JavaScript namespaces.

Comment: Is it possible to use the jQuery namespace?

Comment: @Gemma The `jQuery` object already has a bunch of names defined on it. It wouldn't be wise to just inject a bunch of your own names - that could lead to name collisions, which would then break jQuery's functionality. I recommend a custom global variable (e.g. `MYAPP`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event) { gridClickHandler(oTable); } );
```

Comment: I tried this but the code insider gridClickHandler does not seem to know about $(this)

Comment: What do you expect $(this) to be?

Comment: I need it to be the row I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", gridClickHandler);
gridClickHandler.oTable = oTable;

function gridClickHandler(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target).addClass('row_selected');
}
```

Comment: I tried it before. oTable doesn't seem to be available inside gridClickHandler.

Comment: I was added one string after first string. Try this.

Comment: It gives me SCRIPT5009: 'oTable' is undefined inside the gridClickHandler.